# How to require files in application.scss when the docs call for the file to be required in application.css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-5

So I'm trying to implement the 'bootstrap-tour' gem.  Rails 5 comes with an application.scss file, but the 'bootstrap-tour' gem documentation asks for the following code to be put in the application.css file

```
*= require bootstrap-tour
```

So I created an application.css file and put the code there but if really messes with the styling I've put in the scss file.  If I put the above code in the app.scss file I get the following error

```
couldn't find file 'bootstrap-tour' with type 'text/css'
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.11.1'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.4', '>= 4.4.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.4.1'
gem 'flexbox-rails', '~> 1.0'
gem 'rails_12factor'
gem 'bootstrap-tour-rails'
```

application.scss

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

(And some custom styling here)
```

Answer (score 1):

These are 'magic comments' that sprockets handle. To css/scss they are just `/* */` comment block at the very beginning of a file.

You are missing opening `/*`:

```
/*
*= require 'some_file'
*/
```

But SCSS/SASS [suggests](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#important-note) using `@import` instead of sprockets `require`s - this way sass variables and mixins will be handled properly across files.

Comment: My bad, I didn't include the top half of the .scss file that was mostly comments but it does start with      /*.  But unfortunately I still get the error listed in the post when I try @import "bootstrap-tour-rails";  It seems like bootstrap-tour is looking for the code in a .css file.

Comment: @ChrisWilson Have you restarted app server after adding that gem (sprockets seems not to have picked up new load paths)?

Comment: Yup, I did do that.